# OpenCL buffer allocation and mapping best practice

Tags: c++, c, performance, memory-management, opencl

I am a little confused as to whether my code using OpenCL mapped buffers are correct.

I have two examples, one using CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR and one using CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR. Both work and run on my local machine and OpenCL devices but I am interested in whether this is the correct way of doing the mapping, and whether it should work an all OpenCL devices. I am especially unsure about the USE_HOST_PTR example.

I am only interested in the buffer/map specific operations. I am aware I should do error checking and so forth.

CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR:

```
// pointer to hold the result
int * host_ptr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

d_mem = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE|CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR,
                       size*sizeof(cl_int), NULL, &ret);

int * map_ptr = clEnqueueMapBuffer(command_queue,d_mem,CL_TRUE,CL_MAP_WRITE,
                                   0,size*sizeof(int),0,NULL,NULL,&ret);
// initialize data
for (i=0; i<size;i++) {
  map_ptr[i] = i;
}

ret = clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(command_queue,d_mem,map_ptr,0,NULL,NULL); 

//Set OpenCL Kernel Parameters
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&d_mem);

size_t global_work[1]  = { size };
//Execute OpenCL Kernel
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, 
                             global_work, NULL, 0, 0, NULL);

map_ptr = clEnqueueMapBuffer(command_queue,d_mem,CL_TRUE,CL_MAP_READ,
                             0,size*sizeof(int),0,NULL,NULL,&ret);
// copy the data to result array 
for (i=0; i<size;i++){
  host_ptr[i] = map_ptr[i];
} 

ret = clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(command_queue,d_mem,map_ptr,0,NULL,NULL);        

// cl finish etc
```

CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR:

```
// pointer to hold the result
int * host_ptr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
int i;
for(i=0; i<size;i++) {
  host_ptr[i] = i;
}

d_mem = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE|CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR,
                       size*sizeof(cl_int), host_ptr, &ret);

// No need to map or unmap here, as we use the HOST_PTR the original data
// is already initialized into the buffer?

//Set OpenCL Kernel Parameters
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&d_mem);

size_t global_work[1]  = { size };
//Execute OpenCL Kernel
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, 
                             global_work, NULL, 0, 0, NULL);

// this returns the host_ptr so need need to save it (I assume it always will?)
// although we do need to call the map function
// to ensure the data is copied back.
// There's no need to manually copy it back into host_ptr
// as it uses this by default
clEnqueueMapBuffer(command_queue,d_mem,CL_TRUE,CL_MAP_READ,
                   0,size*sizeof(int),0,NULL,NULL,&ret); 

ret = clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(command_queue,d_mem,map_ptr,0,NULL,NULL);        

// cl finish, cleanup etc
```

Comment: Yes, it seems your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR *you have the chance* that the underlying implementation of OpenCL might use **page-locked memory**.

That means that the page cannot be swapped out to disk and that the transfer between host and device memory would be done *DMA style* without wasting CPU cycles. Therefore in this case CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR would be the best solution.

nVidia has the page-locked (*pinned*) memory feature and they should also use it in their OpenCL implementation. For AMD it's not certain if they do the same. Check **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287346/does-amds-opencl-offer-something-similar-to-cudas-gpudirect)** for more details.

Using CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR would just make the programmer's life easier so *in the unlikely case* when the hardware cannot use page-locked memory you could just use this option.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Could you include a better way of implementing the first example which would not raise performance issues? I am not quite sure I understand why I am not sure the cached copy in device memory is used.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. I think nVidia recommends doing map,allocation,,write,kernel exection,read as per http://www.nvidia.com/content/cudazone/cudabrowser/downloads/papers/nvidia_opencl_bestpracticesguide.pdf and they also recommends using the ALLOC_HOST_PTR instead of USE_HOST_PTR. I think Intel also recommends using ALLOC_HOST_PTR as you otherwise need to ensure correct page boundary. https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/opencl/optimization-guide/index.htm . ARM too: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0538e/BABJHCCH.html

Comment: ALLOC_HOST_PTR may outperform USE_HOST_PTR since the runtime does its best to get the fastest memory available (for example pinned pages).

Comment: Thanks @Cicada. In the case of USE_HOST_PTR would DMA transfers be possible? I guess that depends on how you allocated your memory, however it seems unlikely. So advantage of using USE_HOST_PTR over normal buffers is that if you are on a CPU implementation it would (properly) not need a data copy?

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I believe DMA transfers on USE_HOST_PTR would work **if** you properly allocated the memory as pinned and if the implementation supports it. The advantages of USE_HOST_PTR are simply that the programmer controls the allocation more finely than ALLOC_HOST_PTR.